# Extending the type of an object of an abstract class

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, types, abstract-class

The abstract class `AbstractPanelComponent` has a `config` object that stores some configuration information. When I extend the abstract class, I want to be able to extend the type of `config` to add custom configurations that are required for the implementation.

```
// Default Config Type
export type DefaultPanelConfig = {
    name: string
}

// Type I want to use for extending (to add additional info)
export type CustomConfig = {
    additionalConfig: string;
}

@Component({template: ''})
export abstract class AbstractPanelComponent {
    config: Partial<DefaultPanelConfig> = {};
}

@Component(...)
export class APanelComponent extends AbstractPanelComponent {
    // TODO: Expand the allowed Config somehow...
    override config: Partial<CustomConfig & DefaultPanelConfig> = {}
}
```

Using `override config` serves its purpose, but doesn't seem to be a good style. Is there a better way to implement such a config function, or is this already a good way? For example, I thought about using generics and something like `<T extends Partial<DefaultPanelConfig>>`, but I couldn't really figure out how I would use that. I look forward to your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use generics to make it more elegant. The trick is, that you can directly use `Partial<T & DefaultPanelConfig>` as your `DefaultConfiguration`. By doing so, you can easily extend it with a generic type and set a default generic type so that you don't have to extend it.

In the following you can see a sample implementation:

```
// Default Config Type
type DefaultPanelConfig = {
    name: string
}

// Panel Configuration (Generic, so that it can easily be extended)
// Intersect the default panel configuration with the generic to easily extend it
type PanelConfiguration<T = {}> = Partial<T & DefaultPanelConfig>

// Declare AbstractPanelComponent and set the generic to empty object by default.
abstract class AbstractPanelComponent<T = {}> {
    config: PanelConfiguration<T> = {};
}

/* From here on: Two Test Cases */

// Testing "Default" PanelConfiguration
class APanelComponent extends AbstractPanelComponent {
    // No generic type: Use DefaultPanelConfig and nothing more
    override config: PanelConfiguration = {
        name: "Custom Configuraton", // Valid
        /* additionalConfig: "More Configuration", */ // Invalid (as supposed to)
        /* invalid: "invalid" */ // Invalid (as supposed to)
    }
}

// Declare Custom Config for testing
type CustomConfig = {
    additionalConfig: string;
}

// Testing Extending "Default" Panel Configuration with Custom Configuration
class BPanelComponent extends AbstractPanelComponent<CustomConfig> {
    // Expand the Config by simply adding the Generic Type
    override config: PanelConfiguration<CustomConfig> = {
        name: "Custom Configuraton", // Valid
        additionalConfig: "More Configuration", // Valid
        /* invalid: "invalid" */ // Invalid (as supposed to)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works as expected! If anyone else has more improvement suggestions feel free to let me know! :)